# Call a php function from js - both are in separate files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

File structure is

```
functions/functions.php

function name($name){
   return $name;
}

HTML file
<?php include("./functions/functions.php") ?>
<script src="./js/custom.js"></script>
<button id="btn">click me</button>


JS/custom.js
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var name = <?php echo name("Alex");?>
    alert(name);
});
```

This is not working, can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?
I'm getting : 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ' in the console.

--

```
Edit : Error disappears after I made the change 
var name = '<?php echo name("Alex");?>';
However, I'm still not gettion the alert.
```

Comment: in your custom.js, PHP won't work since its a js file

Comment: @Ghost I understand that, so what is possible solution to it?

Comment: hello @SiddharthPatel, you can use the js internally, same file with php with the button

Comment: @SiddharthPatel use ajax instead, request from server, then alert the response

Comment: rename `JS/custom.js` to `JS/custom.php` and update your html `<script src="./js/custom.php"></script>`

Comment: @Ghost there are several functions in functions.php, how would i call only a single function out of that file?

Comment: @SiddharthPatel create another php file that will handle ajax request, use ajax to call that handler, then use the handler to call the necessary function (from functions.php), get the return value and then respond to that JS ajax call, should be the basic flow

Answer (score 0):

that should be:
var name = "<?php echo name("Alex");?>";

Comment: The error disappers after that, thanx. But I still don't get the alert

Answer (score 0):

You use JQuery selector but don't import jQuery lib to your code, and in java/script code use ready function, your code should be this :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function(e) {
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        var name = <?php echo name("Alex");?>;
        alert(name);
    });
})
</script>
```